# netbeans open a project that not matches with any category

Tags: netbeans, project

It happens to me a lot of times when I want to open a project that no has a main category (html, php, java or something like that) I cannot open. Therefore, I have to open a new one copying all the source or even I have to use other ways to do that. So my question is if is that possible to opening a project directly on Netbeans without matching category?

Thank, I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: What about creating a new project (File / New Project) and select there "xxx project with existing sources"? Then you don't have to copy all your sources. (Another solution is not known to me).

Comment: That's fine although I still have to match it with a more specific category..Anyway, it's enough for my question and I am voting you up...Many thx I used to use eclipse and this option is more clear or maybe was a stupid question. Thank you